# Mobile PWA open previous seen page

Tags: progressive-web-apps, web-app-manifest

I added a web app manifest to my web app and now I can add my web app to my iPhone home screen. I also added google workbox and implemented some caching strategies.
Unfortunately when closing my web app and open it again, it always shows the start screen.
I would like to jump back to the last seen screen automatically (call the last opened url) instead of always jumping to the starting page.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way
-- Subscribe to your router

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    // call a method here to save the current 
    // page to a local storage variable
  }
});
```

When your app opens, if there is a value in local storage, go to that page